# How to break a comma separated string which has SecureInt64 values?

Tags: c#, string, break

I need to break a string that holds comma separated values

```
string ids = "P_0vyx5RVcWblbdw6pql5w~~, BAW1G8b3FuRhR0REQ1JtDw~~"
```

These values are actually SecureInt64.
Which I need to break in a collection, I am trying like below

```
var t = ids.Split(',').ToList().OfType<SecureInt64>();
```

But this is not breaking collection.

When I am pointing to `t` with break points, it says

```
'Enumeration yielded no results'
```

further which I need to translate in Unselcure Ids, something like this,

```
t.Select(k => k.UnsecureValue).ToList()
```

Comment: I assume the string being called `s` and you trying to split on `ids` is just a mistake when writing the question? Otherwise this splits the string just fine for me. Is SecureInt64 a custom class? I've not heard of it before.

Comment: No, my mistake that is ids actually, let me correct it..

Comment: `OfType<T>` will return only objects that are of that type `T` and since your collection is `List<string>` there are no implicit conversion between `string` and `SecureInt64`. That's why you're getting empty collection.

Comment: @m.rogalski I am not sure How can I convert it to SecureInt64

Comment: _"these values are actually SecureInt64"_ - no, they're not. They're just strings. Those strings may represent a SecureInt64 in some way, but you'll have to invert that representation back into a SecureInt64 by decoding it.

Comment: @rupeshmalviya You don't. That's how it works. You've encrypted your `long` and now you have to decrypt it not just convert.

Comment: @m.rogalski shouls I use foreach to cast string to SecureInt64 ?

Comment: when I am using foreach, it says can not convery string to SecureInt64

Comment: You must post the code that shows how you "saved" that numbers... They aren't base64, so it isn't clear how they are saved. The SecureInt64 class that is found when googling for it has no method to export strings similar to the one you have.

Comment: thats the customise class

Comment: @rupeshmalviya Without the source of that `SecureInt64` and the part where you assemble this string we will be unable to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a way to convert the strings to SecureInt64.

```
var t = ids.Split(',')
           .Select(ToSecureInt64)
           .Select(k => k.UnsecureValue) 
           .ToList();

private SecureInt64 ToSecureInt64(string value)
{
   // logic needed to translate a string to SecureInt64.
}
```

Comment: This wont even compile because you've used method that returns `void` and trying to put this into `Func<T, U>` type. Not mentioning that it's not an answer but only irrelevant part.

Comment: as you pointed out in a comment on the question, until we are given more information we can't fill in the logic to help with the conversion.  This answers the rest of the posted question while isolating the part we currently cannot help with.